# Protocol error in Safari for some wikipedia articles' resources

Tags: macos, network, safari, mojave

Safari is displaying the "can't open" page with error

> The error is: “The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error” (NSPOSIXErrorDomain:100)

for URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(franchise) And on some articles, it doesn't load all styles. Using the inspector, I see 2 errors:

> Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error

and one with

> Failed to set referrer policy: The value 'origin-when-crossorigin' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'same-origin', 'origin', 'strict-origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' or 'unsafe-url'.

An example of such site is

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Minor_Outlying_Islands

So far, I've tried

- Safe boot
- Safari's restart in Safe mode(or whatever holding shift while opening Safari does)
- Empty Caches (Develop Menu), deleting all website data (preferences → privacy), not history
- different networks
- and opening the page in Firefox, where everything  is good.

Safari 12.1.1, macOS 10.14.5

Comment: Safari is now at version 13.0.2, while the last version of macOS Mojave is 10.14.6. The two webpages you are having problems with do not exhibit these errors with these versions of Safari and Mojave on two computers I've tested on. I've tried it also on Catalina with no adverse results.

Comment: Oh I just tried the sites and well it is working. When I made the draft, they were problematic. Then at the time of posting(~1 hr) I just fixed formatting, did not check the links.

Comment: Not sure what to do with the question.. close it with something similar, delete it, post an answer saying Wikipedia fixed it etc

Comment: I see this same issue (the styles issue) in Safari v13.0.3 on Mojave 10.14.6, with the same two security policy errors in the developer console.

Comment: @KitGrose I hope wikipedia fixes it for yours too. I did nothing extra, other than putting the laptop to sleep.

Comment: To be clear, the second error ("Failed to set referrer policy") is expected; Wikipedia deliberately includes an invalid referrer policy meta tag of `origin-when-crossorigin` right above the _valid_ policy of `origin-when-cross-origin`, apparently for compatibility issues, so I get those errors in Safari on every page load regardless of whether not the styles load.

It's the protocol error that is apparently an issue, and I'm hoping from my Googling that it's something environmental and will solve itself for me too.

Comment: @KitGrose https://phabricator.wikimedia.org you can file a bug report, or first confirm at https://discourse-mediawiki.wmflabs.org with other people.